# HMAC256 with OpenSSL 3

Tags: c++, openssl

I am new to C++ so go easy :)

I have the following code snippet, however I am using OpenSSL 3, and the compiler is giving various errors: `'HMAC_CTX_new': Since OpenSSL 3.0`. I understand that some of the APIs used below are now deprecated and need updating.

Can someone show me to update the below snippet to work with the updated APIs for OpenSSL 3?

```
const std::string secretKey = "secret";
std::vector<unsigned char> secretKeyByteArray(secretKey.begin(), secretKey.end());
std::vector<unsigned char> signature(signatureRawData.begin(), signatureRawData.end());
std::vector<unsigned char> signatureBytes(HMAC_MAX_MD_CBLOCK);
unsigned int signatureLength = 0;

HMAC_CTX* hmacCtx = HMAC_CTX_new();
HMAC_Init_ex(hmacCtx, secretKeyByteArray.data(), secretKeyByteArray.size(), EVP_sha256(), nullptr);
HMAC_Update(hmacCtx, signature.data(), signature.size());
HMAC_Final(hmacCtx, signatureBytes.data(), &signatureLength);
HMAC_CTX_free(hmacCtx);

std::ostringstream signatureHex;
for (const auto& c : signatureBytes)
    signatureHex << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(c);

std::string requestSignatureHexString = signatureHex.str();
```

Comment: It looks like OpenSSL just merged those 4 functions into one: [HMAC](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/HMAC_CTX_new.html). You should no longer need a context, or need to pass the nullptr to the engine parameter in init.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the code that I use to generate SHA-256 HMAC for OpenSSL 1.1.1 or 3.0:

```
std::string GetHmacSha256(std::string key, std::string msg){
    unsigned int hash_len = 32;
    unsigned char hash[32] = {};

#if OPENSSL_API_COMPAT >= 0x30000000L
    if(!HMAC(EVP_sha256(), &key[0], key.length(),(unsigned char*)&msg[0], msg.length(), hash, &hash_len)){
      std::cout << "[ERROR]: HMAC Generation failed ";
      return {};
    } 
#else
    // This code will work with OpenSSL 1.1. but not with 1.0.1.
    HMAC_CTX *hmac = HMAC_CTX_new();
    HMAC_Init_ex(hmac, &key[0], key.length(), EVP_sha256(), nullptr);
    HMAC_Update(hmac, (unsigned char*)&msg[0], msg.length());
    HMAC_Final(hmac, hash, &hash_len);
    HMAC_CTX_free(hmac);        
#endif

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hash_len; ++i) {
        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2)  << (unsigned int)hash[i];
    }

    return (ss.str());
}
```

Note: My build scripts exports the symbols `OPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0x30000000L` and `OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED` thus making OpenSSL 3.0 as the default with no deprecated APIs.

Details at:

- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/HMAC.html
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/OPENSSL_API_COMPAT.html

---

Update:

Seems like HMAC() is available starting 1.1, so can just use that and no need for the #if.. else...